# MVC mvc two radio button (group) bind to one model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to put two radio buttons (witch are in one group) and bind the choice to one model propery.

my model has this property:

```
public bool is_active { get; set; }
```

my unsuccess try in view was:

```
@{ Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.is_active, true )}  active
@{ Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.is_active, false)}  inactive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code needs to be

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.is_active, true)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.is_active, false)
```

Without the leading `@`, the `RadioButtonFor()` method is executed but its result is not output (wrapping it in a `@{ .. }` code block does not do that and is unnecessary)